How to calculate thi sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \zeta(n) - 1 \right) \cos \left( \frac{n \pi}{3} \right)}{n}$
My question
$$ \displaystyle{\mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \zeta(n) - 1 \right) \cos \left( \frac{n \pi}{3} \right)}{n}}$$
My try to solve the integral
$$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{\zeta \left( n \right) - 1}}{n}\cos \frac{{n\pi }}{3}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{\zeta \left( n \right) - 1}}{n} \cdot \frac{{{e^{i \cdot n \cdot \pi /3}} + {e^{ - i \cdot n \cdot \pi /3}}}}{2}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {\zeta \left( n \right) - 1} \right){e^{i \cdot n \cdot \pi /3}}}}{n}}$$
I don't know how to go further

Can you please provide some context? That is, what tools are you allowed to find the sum?

Replacement of $\zeta(n)-1=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^n}$ gives
$$
\mathcal{S} 
{=
 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \zeta(n) - 1 \right) \cos \left( \frac{n \pi}{3} \right)}{n}
\\=
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^n}\frac{ e^{\imath \frac{n \pi}{3}}+e^{-\imath \frac{n \pi}{3}}}{2n}
\\=
 \sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^ \frac{\imath\pi}{3}}{k}\right)^n\frac{1}{2n}
+
\left(\frac{e^\frac{-\imath\pi}{3}}{k}\right)^n\frac{1}{2n}
\\=
 -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty
\left\{\ln\left(1-\frac{e^\frac{\imath\pi}{3}}{k}\right)+\frac{e^\frac{\imath\pi}{3}}{k}
\right\}
 -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty
\left\{
\ln\left(1-\frac{e^\frac{-\imath\pi}{3}}{k}\right)+\frac{e^\frac{-\imath\pi}{3}}{k}
\right\}.
}
$$
Using the following factorization of $\ln \Gamma(z)$
$$
\ln \Gamma(z)=-\gamma z-\ln z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)
$$
and a bit a simplification, we finally obtain
$$
\mathcal{S}=\frac{1-\gamma+\ln \Gamma(-e^{ \frac{\imath\pi}{3}})\Gamma(-e^{ \frac{-\imath\pi}{3}})}{2},
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

$$\Gamma(-e^{\frac{\pi i}3})\Gamma(-e^{\frac{-\pi i}3})=\Big|\Gamma\Big(\frac12-1-\frac{\sqrt 3}2i\Big)\Big|^2=\frac{\pi}{\cosh\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2},\frac1{\frac14+\big(\frac{\sqrt3}2\big)^2}=\frac{\pi}{\cosh\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2}$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Beautiful! Would be happy you add this to my answer and (most suitably) have a share of the upvotes.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\cal S} & \equiv \color{#44f}{\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{\bracks{\zeta(n) - 1}
\cos\pars{n\pi/3} \over n}} =
\Re\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\bracks{\zeta(n) - 1}{\pars{\expo{\pi\ic/3}}^{n} \over n}
\\[5mm] & = \Re\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\bracks{\zeta(n) - 1}
\int_{0}^{\expo{\pi\ic/3}}t^{n - 1}\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\int_{0}^{\expo{\pi\ic/3}}\bracks{%
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\zeta(n)t^{n - 1} -
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}t^{n - 1}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\int_{0}^{\expo{\pi\ic/3}}\braces{%
\bracks{\rule{0pt}{4mm}-\gamma - \Psi\pars{1 - t}} - {t \over 1- t}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & = \Re\bracks{\rule{0pt}{5mm}-\gamma t +\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 - t}} + t + \ln\pars{1 - t}}
_{\,0}^{\,\expo{\pi\ic/3}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2} -{1 \over 2}\gamma +
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{{1 \over 2} + {\root{3}\ic \over 2}}\Gamma\pars{{1 \over 2} - {\root{3}\ic \over 2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2} -{1 \over 2}\gamma +
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{\pi \over \cosh\pars{\pi\root{3}/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 2} -{1 \over 2}\gamma +
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{\pi} - {1 \over 2}\ln\pars{ \cosh\pars{{\root{3} \over 2}\pi}}}} \approx -0.2322\\ &
\end{align}
See $\ds{\bf 6.3.14}$ in A & S
and $\ds{\bf 6.1.30}$ in A & S.
